# Reorder x values by factor in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Let's say I have the following command that generates a plot

```
mpg %>% filter(manufacturer == "toyota") %>%
  ggplot( aes(x=model, y=hwy, fill=class)) + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 20, hjust = 1)) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

[Link to the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kw0IC.png)

Is there a way in which I can order the x labels by factor, such that all boxplots with the same class appear next to each other?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `factor` to reorder.  `arrange` the data by 'class', 'model', then convert the 'model' to `factor` with `levels` specified as the `unique` values of 'model' and rerun the `ggplot`

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
mpg %>% 
  filter(manufacturer == "toyota") %>% 
  arrange(class, model) %>% 
  mutate(model = factor(model, levels = unique(model))) %>% 
  ggplot( aes(x=model, y=hwy, fill=class)) + 
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 20, hjust = 1)) +
    geom_boxplot()
```

-output

[image]

---

Another option is `fct_reorder`

```
library(forcats)
mpg %>% 
  filter(manufacturer == "toyota") %>%
  ggplot( aes(x=fct_reorder(model, class), y=hwy, fill=class)) + 
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 20, hjust = 1)) +
    geom_boxplot()
```